# SQL Server - How to use convert with ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Something like the example below:

```
SELECT SSN, Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Hours) ISNULL(Hours, '')
```

where I want to convert an int to varchar and at the same time set the null values as an empty string. How can I do to make this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Hours), '')
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option if you are on 2012+ would be to use

```
SELECT CONCAT(Hours,'')
```

which has the same end result of converting to string and returning empty string instead of NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your convert in the `isnull`;

```
SELECT 
SSN
,Name
,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Hours), '')
```

This way it will allow for the nulls to be pulled on the conversion, you won't be able to do the isnull inside the convert as a zero length character won't be compatible with an int field (or other number only field).